# Resize window and move elements, how to change coords

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, air, flex4.5

I have an adobe air application with 1024x600.
Now i want to enable resizing. When I give percentage sizes for elements, like a datagrid, grid changes his size correctly.

But what can I do with the position of the buttons ?
When I change the width of my application, the datagrid grows, but the buttons stay on their
position.

How can I change that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use relative values instead of fixed pixles. For example

```
  function resizeListener (e:Event):void  {

             button.x = stage.stageWidth / 2;

  }
```

In mxml u can use pixel or percent values for the width.
Also you can use the percentWidth property!

This is all well documented [live docs](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_3.html)

for positoning you will have to make it a [constraint-based layout](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=size_position_5.html)

Comment: this can't be the right solution. what if I have 1000 buttons ? Isn't there a way to do that in MXML?

Comment: Sry, somehow though u wanted to do it in as3. Updated answer.

Comment: But the width option doesn't change the x coord. I don't need a growing button by resizing, I need a button, which is moving by resizing

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned, actionscript approach works fine, if you always want it at the same place. In mxml, I often use constraint-based layout with a 0 horizontal position so it will go left/right as you would expect. On the y axis, sometimes it's a judgment call if you really want the additional space with 0-base so I sometimes keep the Y dependent upon the top, if the situation dictates.

However another approach I use is to put button groups or object groups inside an HGroup or other container and then use contraint-based or pixel-based positioning of that larger object so nothing within it changes sizes but the group of objects re-positions to where you would like